# Angular2 pass object to child only once

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components, detail(parent) and update(child).
I want the update component to have it's initial values (a form) set depending on an object that the detail component has.

I am trying to do that with the @Input decorator, so i have something like:

```
<app-component-update [childObject]="childObject"></app-component-update>
```

I am able to get the value in the child. However whenever i update the form in the child, the parent is updated, which is something that i don't want. What is a good approach to sending the value just one time?
I tried cloning the object (lodash's cloneDeep) but i have my doubts about that approach.

Answer (score 0):

there are two way inform to components. EventEmitter and Services. check the offical example. there is good video on [angular-university](https://angular-university.io)